# In debug mode javascript is working fine but if i am running it directly failure message is coming in Firefox

Tags: javascript

This is the function :

```
addproducttocart: function (urladd) {

    if (this.loadWaiting != false) {
        return;
    }
    this.setLoadWaiting(true);

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: urladd,
        type: 'post',
        success: this.successprocess,
        complete: this.resetLoadWaiting,
        error: this.ajaxFailure
    });



}
```

it is working fine when i am executing it in debug mode line by line but giving error while executing directly or in normal mode in Firefox.
I am not getting how solve this problem your help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not enough information provided. What do success, complete and error look like, what error do you get?

Comment: On Success i am redirecting to some other page,Complete setting and removing load image according to the value and error will display some text i am setting when function is not success.That text is coming as error.My doubt is  why on debug mode function is giving success while directly its giving error

Comment: Could be a timing issue. If you alert instead of using console.log

Comment: Thank for your response, I don't want to use alert here any other option is there to fix it?

Comment: I did not suggest you should alert. When you debug, you block the execution LIKE an alert would do. So far your comments have not given me more to go on.